# How to translate DB result into a json file

Tags: php, json

In my project, I want to deposit DB result data to a file named datagrid.json.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
include("DB.php");
$sql="select aa,bb,cc,dd from OA where sysnum='TZ20171204173151317';";
$sel=$conn->query($sql);

$arr=array();
while($row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $arr[]=$row;
}
$result["rows"]=$arr;
echo json_encode($result) > datagrid.json;
?>
```

I can fetch DB data successfully, here is my SQL data result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| aa         | bb           | cc           | dd                  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 123.jpg    | .jpg         | Tom          | 2017-12-04 17:31:51 |
| 1.jpg      | .jpg         | Stack        | 2017-12-04 17:31:56 |
| test.jpg   | .jpg         | Jack         | 2017-12-04 17:32:00 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

The file of datagrid.json should be in my linux server.But it is not exist.

The correct content of datagrid.json should be :

```
{"rows":[{"aa":"123.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Tom","dd":"2017-12-04 17:31:51"},
         {"aa":"1.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Stack","dd":"2017-12-04 17:31:56"},
         {"aa":"test.jpg","bb":".jpg","cc":"Jack","dd":"2017-12-04 17:32:00"}
]}
```

How to realize? How to deposit these data to a json file in linux server?
Who can help me?

Comment: What json format are you currently getting?

Comment: Maybe echo json_encode($result) > datagrid.json is wrong, I cannot find datagrid.json